# Wordpress плагин выдает js ошибку, как исправить?

Tags: wordpress

установил плагин Tooltips, он работает но выдает пару ошибок в js в том числе

*jQuery(...).qtip is not a function*

*jQuery(...).directory is not a function*

И за этих ошибок дальнейшие скрипты тоже не могут работать, ( проверял , отключал плагин все работает). Вопрос, каким образом можно убрать данные ошибки, ибо они выводяться автоматически

Comment: Запускать tooltips надо правильно, с указанием зависимости от jQuery

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script